# Obtaining an analytical solutions a given system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

The system of differential equations are of the form:
$$v(y) + C_{1} v(y)^3 = C_2 \dfrac{du(y)}{dy}$$
$$\dfrac{dv(y)}{dy} + C_3 u(y) = C_4$$
The boundary and symmetry conditions are:
$$v(y=0)=0$$
$$u(y=\pm H)=0$$

#### Edit

I tried solving the systwm with

```
DSolve[
  {c2 u'[y] == v[y] + c1 v[y]^3, 
   v'[y] + c3 u[y] == c4, 
   u[H] == 0, v[0] == 0}, 
  {v[y], u[y]}, y]
```

However, Mathematica is returning my input without solving the e.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in *Mathematica*? Have you already seen `DSolve[]`?

Comment: Have you tried using Mathematica? If so, it would be helpful to show some code.

Comment: I had tried solving  using  `DSolve[{c2 u'[y] == v[y] + c1 v[y]^3 , v'[y] + c3 u[y] == c4, 
  u[H] == 0, v[0] == 0}, {v[y], u[y]}, y])`. However, Mathematica was returning my input back without solving it.

Comment: "However, Mathematica was returning my input back without solving it." - that means `DSolve[]` is not aware of a closed-form solution, if one exists.

Comment: With this code: `DSolve[{c2 u'[y] == v[y] + c1 v[y]^3, v'[y] + c3 u[y] == c4, 
  u[H] == 0, v[0] == 0}, {v, u}, y]` it returned me a result. Much too long though to be useful.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Unfortunately, didn't work for me. Mathematica returned my input back.

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using?  MM 12 returns an awful expression involving `InverseFunction`s (I suspect this is what @AlexeiBoulbitch got), but it doesn't return that input unevaluated.

Comment: @ Michael Seifert Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting the derivative of $v'(y)+C_3 u(y)=C_4$ into the first ODE we have

$$
a v(y)^3+b v''(y)+v(y)=0
$$

which seems to have a closed form

```
DSolve[v[y] + a v[y]^3 + b v''[y] == 0, v, y]
```